# How to Create a Custom Control in JavaFX

Tags: javafx, controls, skin

Here I created my own control, with a canvas and ScrollBar. I didn't manage to correctly intercept the keyboard shortcuts or key pressed. When adding another component to the scene (here a TextField, commented), no keyboard events are received. Maybe I missed something about the focus?

Also, I had to add some --export to Gradle, to avoid some errors with the module.

```
plugins {
    id 'application'
    id 'org.openjfx.javafxplugin' version '0.0.8'
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

javafx {
    version = "15.0.1"
    modules = [ 'javafx.controls', 'javafx.graphics' ]
}

run {
    jvmArgs = ['--add-exports=javafx.controls/com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior=ALL-UNNAMED',
               '--add-exports=javafx.controls/com.sun.javafx.scene.control.inputmap=ALL-UNNAMED']
}
mainClassName = 'com.wisecoders.textpane.CustomControlApp'
```

```
package com.wisecoders.textpane;


import com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.BehaviorBase;
import com.sun.javafx.scene.control.inputmap.InputMap;
import com.sun.javafx.scene.control.inputmap.KeyBinding;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.geometry.Orientation;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.canvas.Canvas;
import javafx.scene.canvas.GraphicsContext;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.scene.input.Clipboard;
import javafx.scene.input.ClipboardContent;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyCode;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class CustomControlApp extends Application {

    private final BorderPane root = new BorderPane();
    private final Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 250);

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        stage.setTitle("Sample Canvas");

        root.setTop( new TextField());
        MyControl control = new MyControl();
        root.setCenter(control);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.sizeToScene();
        Platform.runLater( control::requestFocus );
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    class MyControl extends Control {

        private final StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder();

        public MyControl(){
            setPrefSize(400, 400 );
            setFocusTraversable(true);
            setOnMouseClicked(ev-> requestFocus());
            requestFocus();
            setOnKeyTyped(ev-> { if ( !ev.isShortcutDown() ){
                addTextToBuffer( ev.getCharacter() );
            }});
        }
        public void addTextToBuffer( String str ){
            buffer.append( str );
            ((MyControlSkin)getSkin()).paintCanvas();
        }

        public String getText(){ return buffer.toString(); }

        @Override protected Skin<?> createDefaultSkin() {
            return new MyControlSkin(this);
        }
    }

    class MyControlSkin extends SkinBase<MyControl> {

        final BorderPane borderPane = new BorderPane();
        final ScrollBar rightScroll = new ScrollBar();
        final Canvas canvas = new Canvas();
        final MyControlBehavior behavior;

        public MyControlSkin(MyControl control) {
            super(control);
            behavior = new MyControlBehavior( control );
            rightScroll.setOrientation(Orientation.VERTICAL);
            borderPane.setRight( rightScroll );
            borderPane.setCenter(canvas);
            canvas.setWidth( 150);
            canvas.setHeight( 150 );
            getChildren().add( borderPane );
            paintCanvas();
        }

        public void paintCanvas(){
            GraphicsContext gr = canvas.getGraphicsContext2D();
            gr.clearRect( 0,0, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight());
            gr.setFill( Color.BLACK);
            gr.fillText( "Buff:" + getSkinnable().getText(), 30, 20 );
        }

        @Override
        public void dispose() {
            super.dispose();
            behavior.dispose();
            getChildren().removeAll();
        }
    }

    class MyControlBehavior extends BehaviorBase<MyControl> {

        final InputMap<MyControl> inputMap;

        public MyControlBehavior(MyControl control) {
            super(control);
            this.inputMap = createInputMap();
            addDefaultMapping( inputMap, new InputMap.KeyMapping(new KeyBinding(KeyCode.C).shortcut().ctrl(), e-> copy() ) );
        }

        public void copy(){
            final Clipboard clipboard = Clipboard.getSystemClipboard();
            final ClipboardContent content = new ClipboardContent();
            content.putString( getNode().getText() );
            clipboard.setContent(content);
        }

        @Override
        public InputMap<MyControl> getInputMap() {
            return inputMap;
        }
    }
    
}
```

Comment: [mcve] please .. that said: don't forget that Key events are delivered to the focusOwner only

Comment: Thank you for your reply. You are right, I improved the text and the code in the post. I added also setFocusable(), but this does not help always.

Comment: hmm .. worksforme, provided I transfer focus with tab. A couple (not necessarily related :) comments: a) requestFocus in skin's constructor has no effect because the control is not yet part of the scenegraph (do it after showing the stage) b) your control has no means to grab focus on mouse events (no automatics, you'll have to implement it) c) the pattern for skin creation is wrong: don't keep a reference (super already has it), create and return the custom skin in createDefaultSkin d) your skin must implement dispose to cleanup (dispose the behavior, remove direct children it installed)

Comment: Thank you for your feedback, is great. I modified the code directly in the question. May I ask, what is good the behavior for? First, I need to put the --add-exports in gradle to be able to use it. Second, maybe I can set the shortcuts and input map directly in the control? I also moved the keyTyped() from behavior to the control. And this also calls the skin to repaint the canvas. I am not sure if this is the right approach.

Comment: The 'add-exports' means the behavior is implementing interfaces that are not accessible by default, right? I am wondering why I should use the behavior any more. Do you have any idea?